# Combining multiple SELECT Queries from multiple views to count data

Tags: mysql

So I'm trying to build what amounts to a report from several MySQL views that I have already written.  Each one of the views has three columns and looks something like this

```
View ABC:
-------------------------------
|    A    |    B    |    C    |
|         |         |         |
-------------------------------
|  data1  |   asdf  |    3    |
|  data1  |   jkl;  |    1    |
-------------------------------
```

Assume that there are three other views which are structured identically, named DEF, GHI, and JKL.  In view DEF, the last column is named D, in GHI the last column is named E, and in JKL the last column is named F.

In each of the views, the value in the A column should be the same for all rows (It's for another way to solve the problem I'm having which doesn't completely rely on MySQL, but I'm sure there must be a better way).

What I'm trying to do is this:

```
View ABC:
-------------------------------------------------------------
|    A    |    B    |    C    |    D    |    E    |    F    |
|         |         |         |         |         |         |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|  data1  |   asdf  |    3    |    0    |    2    |    7    |
|  data1  |   jkl;  |    1    |    1    |    0    |    0    |
|  data2  |   lmno  |    0    |    1    |    2    |    17   |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

So my first thought would be to LEFT OUTER JOIN on the B field, like so:

```
SELECT ABC.*, DEF.D, GHI.E, JKL.F 
FROM ABC 
LEFT OUTER JOIN DEF ON ABC.B = DEF.B 
LEFT OUTER JOIN GHI ON ABC.B = GHI.B
LEFT OUTER JOIN JKL ON ABC.B = JKL.B
```

That's all well and good; it fills in zeroes with NULL, which I can easily COALESCE into 0.  However, the issue is if there is a row in one of the DEF, GHI, or JKL views where the username doesn't match one in ABC; that row is simply omitted from my SELECT (due to this being a LEFT OUTER JOIN).  RIGHT OUTER JOIN suffers the same issue.

Is there a way to perform a full outer join such that any B that occurs in any of the four views will have a row in my SELECT?  I've tried embedding some other selects, but unfortunately that seems to repeat rows and data values in an unacceptable way in the result of the SELECT.  From looking at the documentation, I don't think MySQL supports a full outer join (at least not that I could find), and even if it did, I don't know how I could get the username from the other views into the username column in the SELECT statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a [FULL OUTER JOIN](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Full_outer_join). Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be supported directly in MySQL, however you can achieve the result by doing `UNION`s of `LEFT JOIN`s and `RIGHT JOIN`s.

From: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

> **Posted by barbarina on September 12 2006 2:17pm**
>
> You can emulate FULL OUTER JOIN using
>   UNION (from MySQL 4.0.0 on):
>
> with two tables t1, t2:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
> UNION 
> SELECT * FROM t1 RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
> ```
>
> with three tables t1, t2, t3:
>
> ```
> SELECT * 
> FROM 
>   t1 
>   LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
>   LEFT JOIN t3 ON t2.id = t3.id 
> UNION 
> SELECT * 
> FROM t1 
>   RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
>   LEFT JOIN t3 ON t2.id = t3.id 
> UNION 
> SELECT * 
> FROM 
>   t1 
>   RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
>   RIGHT JOIN t3 ON t2.id = t3.id
> ```

Comment: Upon thinking about it some more, I think I've come to the conclusion that a FULL OUTER JOIN actually is not the way to go and that I'm forced into performing multiple SELECTS and UNIONing them together.  Using this logic, I was able to produce the final query (which I'll post in another answer as it's too long for this comment).

Answer (score 0):

So Adam Franco's solution was actually pretty close, except they all used LEFT OUTER JOINs instead of a combination of LEFT and RIGHT.  Given that I had to UNION, all of the columns had to match up in order, so a combination of LEFT and RIGHT OUTER JOINs was out.  I managed to cobble this together after thinking about UNIONs from his suggestion:

```
SELECT ABC.B, ABC.C, DEF.D, GHI.E, JKL.F
FROM ABC 
LEFT OUTER JOIN DEF ON DEF.B = ABC.B 
LEFT OUTER JOIN GHI ON ABC.B = GHI.B
LEFT OUTER JOIN JKL ON JKL.B = ABC.B

UNION DISTINCT

SELECT DEF.B, ABC.C, DEF.D, GHI.E, JKL.F
FROM `DEF` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ABC ON DEF.B = ABC.B 
LEFT OUTER JOIN GHI ON DEF.B = GHI.B
LEFT OUTER JOIN JKL ON JKL.B = DEF.B

UNION DISTINCT

SELECT GHI.B, ABC.C, DEF.D, GHI.E, JKL.F
FROM `GHI` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ABC ON GHI.B = ABC.B 
LEFT OUTER JOIN DEF ON DEF.B = GHI.B
LEFT OUTER JOIN JKL ON JKL.B = GHI.B

UNION DISTINCT

SELECT ABC.B, ABC.C, DEF.D, GHI.E, JKL.F
FROM `ABC` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN DEF ON DEF.B = ABC.B 
LEFT OUTER JOIN GHI ON ABC.B = GHI.B
LEFT OUTER JOIN JKL ON JKL.B = ABC.B

UNION DISTINCT

SELECT DEF.B, ABC.D, DEF.D, GHI.E, JKL.F
FROM `DEF` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ABC ON DEF.B = ABC.B 
LEFT OUTER JOIN GHI ON DEF.B = GHI.B
LEFT OUTER JOIN JKL ON JKL.B = DEF.B

UNION DISTINCT

SELECT JKL.B, ABC.D, DEF.D, GHI.E, JKL.F
FROM `JKL` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ABC ON JKL.B = ABC.B 
LEFT OUTER JOIN DEF ON DEF.B = JKL.B
LEFT OUTER JOIN GHI ON JKL.B = GHI.B
```

I had to use UNION DISTINCT to avoid duplicate rows being added, but other than that it was pretty straight forward.